# IE 9 debugger how to get variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, dom

My code not working on IE 9 but fine in Firefox:

```
var denomAmount = j(this).closest('.denom').children('.denomValue').eq(0).val();
```

I want to find what is `eq(0)` going to return but IE9 debugger give list of messy code without anything useful:

```
obj = j(this).closest('.denom').children('.denomValue').eq(0);
```

show me hundred varaibles of `obj` but all of them have a value of something like this:

```
function(a,b,d){if(a||a===0)return
this.animate(S(hide,3),a,b,d);else{a=0;for(b=this.length;a<b;a++)
{d=c.css(this[a],display);d!=="none" c.data(this[a],olddisplay,d)}for(a=0;a<b;a++)this[a].style.display=none;return this}}
```

I just want the value and basic attributes of obj.

Comment: What context is `j(this)` being called?

Comment: if you think ie9 is hard, be thankful you werent doing web development 8 years ago

Comment: Should work just fine in IE, as long as `j` is jQuery and `this` is an element ?

Comment: In your case, `obj` is a jQuery object, so IE prints out the object's properties.  Try to log some specific info about the element.  Like: `console.log(obj.prop('id'))`

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat, Thanks, but I get Obj doesn't support property or 'prop'

Comment: @Dreamer: I guess you're using an older jQuery version, try `console.log(obj.attr('id'))` instead.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat The log is empty "LOG:" so I bet it doesn't have an id attribute...Seems IE cannot find a children element using `eq()`. And good catch !! I am on Jquery 1.4.... :(

Comment: @Dreamer: How about `console.log(obj.length)`?

Answer (score 1):

IE does not bind context of `this` to console. Use a query selector like id or class to get the element. From there, you should be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not bind context of `this` to console"?

Comment: A call to `this` will return the calling object, be it the document, or a function, or an object, or something explicitly define by using the `call` or `apply` method on a code object. When running `j(this)` in the console, it will return this object that the console binds to the function, but it will be different then the `$(this)` found when that same peice of code is run in your script, since in the script, a peice of html calls the code and this returns an object where `.closest('.denom')` might make sense.  That is the cause of the unexpected results.